# excel:index Match to be passed to chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, excel-formula, excel-charts

I have two sheets, i.e. list of columnname(Col Sheet) and the other one(data Sheet) contains data where first three columns are static and remaining columns can change.I have defined an index match function in excel which correctly identifies the column name from col sheet  finds it in data sheet.
 The index match function is like this:

```
=INDEX(Data!1:1,1,MATCH(Chart_Range!A2,Data!1:1,0))
```

Now, I want to use this index match function in charts to identify the column name in data sheet and plot it against one of the three static columns.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Chart can't do any calculation on their own, they can only plot data. But calculations are easy for the worksheet. Use your formula to calculate the values in a column in the sheet. Then plot this column in your chart.